# How do we parse poems with unusual grammar?

Tags: poetry

I quote here without typography, because I don't know how to show it on stack

> Morning breeze morning breeze murmurs / on water trembles leaves / young
> trees above green branches / birds cascade / sing sweetly the east is
> bright. / See, already light's white / the sea a mirror / to clear sky / light
> frost pearled / the high hills golden"

This is from the poet John Riley, written before his death in 1978.

We can add punctuation to the sentences and parse it that way. But I don't want to do that in this long poem Czargrad: I don't believe that is how he wrote the poems (just ignored punctuation), nor that it's the best reading.

**When does unusual grammar suggest figuration, and how you can then think the sentence without an anything goes approach?**

I think I can ignore 'cascade' and 'trembles' as figurative language.

> Morning breeze morning breeze murmurs on "water leaves young trees" "above green branches birds sing sweetly 'the east is bright' ".

Leaving the breeze to speak.

The next sentence also has unusual grammar. I want to think of brightness standing for the water cycle. Leaving, most economically:

> See, already precipitations white the sea a mirror to clear sky light frost discharged from the high hills golden.

Rain in the hills changes the sea from a mirror to a frost white.

**What methods can we use to determine how unusual grammar in poetry should be parsed?**

Comment: The answer will depend on the poem on question. Would a slight rewrite (to ask only specifically about the quoted poem) preserve your intent?

Comment: dunno @bobble I can roll back and edit. I'm definitely not only interested in this one poem, and if you can class is as an X poem, that would be helpful

Comment: I've made a small edit, to focus the question on *what methods to use in parsing*, as opposed to *how to parse*, which will be unique to each poem. I believe this was your intent?